# What happened when I use ros-load to load cram-language

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [this ros answer page](http://answers.ros.org/question/2047/why-rosmake-cram_pl-says-cause-fatal-errors) to use roslisp_repl package to load cram-language.

When I load cram-language, it seems have trouble, so it appear backtrace.

When I choose abort the message shows:

```
  Evaluation aborted on component #:ALEXANDRIA not found, required by #<SYSTEM "cram-utilities" {1003186611}>.
```

[image: image description]

How to do next?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11222/what-happened-when-i-use-ros-load-to-load-cram-language/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like you didn't do a `rosmake cram_language`. Alexandria is a 3rd party library that is downloaded by rosmake.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1